# Starting a new activity but with different intents

Tags: xamarin.android

Normally, if I want to start a new activity I can use

```
StartActivity(typeof(foo));
```

This is fine.

I can also set an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(foo));
StartActivity(i);
```

Problem is this. I have Activity A. This fires off Activity B. However, I need to fire off Activity B after using PutExtra on an intent. If I do

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityB));
```

monodroid gets rightly annoyed as I'm defining a new Intent from within an Activity.

Is there a way to do this

(psuedocode)

```
[Activity]
public partial class A
{
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
   {
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout);
       Button btnClick = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnClicky);
       btnClick.Click += new EventHandler(button_click);
   }

   private void button_Click(object s, EventArgs e)
   {
       Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(B)); // <- gets annoyed
       i.PutExtra("foo", 1);
       i.PutExtra("bar", true);
       StartActivity(i);
   }
 }
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

PFJ

Comment: What exactly happens when you do it like that? How does it get annoyed? What is the error you get?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "gets annoyed"? You're allowed to create intents from activities, so that code is fine. In fact, StartActivity(typeof(foo)) is just a shortcut that creates the intent for you under the hood.

Comment: By "gets annoyed" the compiler was telling me that I was doing it wrong. I've managed to fix it another way (I do like doing that), so thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you please answer your own question and accept it then?

Comment: Looks like I needed to add a using which wasn't needed elsewhere. Thanks for the answers and sorry for the delay in getting back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to add a using which wasn't needed elsewhere.

Thanks for the answers and sorry for the delay in getting back :)

Promise that in future, I'll make sure things are clearer.